# Formbuilder generated was not right for the render partial in rails 3.2.8 ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formbuilder

We using the following code to pass a formbuilder to a render partial in new.js.erb:

```
  <% @f = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(:expense, @expense, self, {}, proc {} ) %> 
  var rpt = $("<%= escape_javascript(render 'expenses/expense_for', :f => @f) %>");
```

The @f is the formbuilder generated for the partial. The error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x60c6828>):
    1: <%= f.input :expense_for, :label => "栏目： ", :collection => @expense_for  %>
```

The partial _expense_for.html.erb is:

```
<%= f.input :expense_for, :label => "栏目： ", :collection => @expense_for  %>
```

As the error shows, the input method was not defined for f formbuilder in partial above. What could be wrong with the formbuilder passed in? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` has no method input. That's true as far as I know. `input` is a SimpleForm or Formtastic method, try with `f.select` (you'll need to change the arguments).

Comment: Make sense! Can you provide detail about implementation? Thanks.

Comment: <%= f.select :expense_for, @expense_for.map { |expense| [expense.name, expense.id] }  %>

Comment: Works like charm. What we did is to replace the expense_for partial with: <%= f.select :expense_for, @expense_for.map { |expense| [expense, expense] } %>. Thanks. BTW. how to add a label to it?

Comment: <%=f.label :expense_for, 'Expense' %> adds the label.